# Insert Query with PHP PDO and MySQL, Eventually Referencing a Foreign Key

Tags: php, mysql, database, azure, pdo

I recognize this question may have been asked many times but I also feel that PHP syntax is so sensitive that I should have somebody else review what I have done so far.

This application is a quiz of sorts that tallies each answer at the end.

I am running a MySQL server on CloudDB through Azure. This application passes variables through the POST header with an HTML form. I am attempting to write the data submitted to a database. I have authentication setup that references the Users table. I have also created a Submissions table. I would like the submissions table to have a UserID foreign key.

For now, I have disabled the UserID foreign key and am just attempting to write to the submissions table with the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'inc/header.php';
require_once('inc/db.php');

if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
    die("Redirecting to index.php");
}

if( isset($_POST['first_name']) ) {

    var $var1 = $_POST['first_name'];
    var $var2 = $_POST['last_name'];
    var $var3 = $_POST['birthdate'];
    var $var4 = $_POST['phone'];
    var $var5 = $_POST['address'];
    var $var6 = $_POST['qfinalinput'];

    $query = "
        INSERT INTO submissions {
            firstname,
            lastname,
            birthdate,
            phone,
            address,
            qfinalvalue
        } VALUES {
            :firstname,
            :lastname,
            :birthdate,
            :phone,
            :address,
            :qfinalvalue
        }
    ";

    $query_params = array {
        ':firstname' => $var1,
        ':lastname' => $var2,
        ':birthdate' => $var3,
        ':phone' => $var4,
        ':address' => $var5,
        ':qfinalvalue' => $var6
    };

    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        echo "PDO error :" . $ex->getMessage();
    }
}

?>
```

When I look at the Network tab of the Inspect Element console, I see the values passed successfully. All of my POST variables are passing properly and when I reload the page, it prompts me to resubmit the data.

Problem is: I do not get the page to display anything. I have html after the php that does not load.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Updated my post, apologies.

Comment: Runs through lots of question pages so if you want to know whats wrong with final page after graph you had better show us whats going on in that script also

Answer (score 0):

One thing to think about is here

```
if( isset($_POST['first_name']) ) {

    var $var1 = $_POST['first_name'];
    var $var2 = $_POST['last_name'];
    var $var3 = $_POST['birthdate'];
    var $var4 = $_POST['phone'];
    var $var5 = $_POST['address'];
    var $var6 = $_POST['qfinalinput'];
```

If you are going to use all those fields you should test that they all exist rather than just the first one. Remember `isset()` can test more than one field at a time, like this :

```
if( isset($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'],
          $_POST['birthdate'],  $_POST['phone'],
          $_POST['address'],    $_POST['qfinalinput']
         ) 
  ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know which PHP version you are using, but in my test, I found several PHP syntax and SQL syntax in your code. By the way, my PHP version was 5.6.1.

```
$query = "
        INSERT INTO submissions {
            firstname,
            lastname,
            birthdate,
            phone,
            address,
            qfinalvalue
        } VALUES {
            :firstname,
            :lastname,
            :birthdate,
            :phone,
            :address,
            :qfinalvalue
        }
    ";
```

should change braces “**`{}`**” to parentheses “**`()`**”.

Also we can write a sample SQL sentence like “`INSERT INTO submissions {firstname} VALUES {'somebody'}`” in a MySQL workbench. It might throw a SQL syntax exception.

And in PHP, when we declare an array variable, we also use parentheses like

```
$query_params = array (
        ':firstname' => $var1,
        ':lastname' => $var2,
        ':birthdate' => $var3,
        ':phone' => $var4,
        ':address' => $var5,
        ':qfinalvalue' => $var6
    );
```

Furthermore, in your code, after finishing SQL operations, there was no redistricting functions to your HTML page. This sentence

```
$stmt->execute($query_params);
```

just return a Boolean variable.